# solutions escape to infinity in finite time

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider ODE $x'=x^2$ on $R$. Find its solution with initial value $x_0$. Are the solutions defined for all the time or do they escape to infinity in finite time?

The solution seems to be $x(t)=1/(1/x_0-t)$ by separation of variables, but what should we say to conclude "escaping to infinity in finite time"? $x^2$ is not globally Lipschitz or something else? I am confused about this part.

Thanks!

Comment: You have $\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{x_0}} x(t) = +\infty$ hence the "escape to infinity"

Comment: But how about the "finite time" part?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x_0}$ is finite (for $x_0 \neq 0$). You should plot the solution to see what it means

Comment: There is also one solution that does not blow up at any finite time (positive or negative), namely $x(t) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider $x_0>0$, $\lim_{x \to (1/x_0)^-} = +\infty$. That is, you have blowup in finite time: it only takes time $1/x_0$ for the solution to blow up. By contrast $x=e^t$ does blow up, but it takes infinite time to do so. In light of Picard-Lindelof, this is only possible because the right side is not globally Lipschitz in $x$.

Comment: Is proving not being globally Lipschitz sufficient to conclude escape to infinity in finite time?

Comment: @askquesitons Infinity, not necessarily. Not being Lipschitz continuous on a domain just means that a unique solution is not guaranteed to exist on that domain.